# How to have an equal spacing between the columns in a row as we have on left and right in Bootstrap 3 grid?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to have an equal spacing between all block in a row as we have on left and right. By default bootstrap adds padding to all columns on both side. And it doesn't render extra spacing to left side of first column and right side of last column in a row because of

```
.row {
margin-right: -15px;
margin-left: -15px;}
```

But in inner side we get double spacing which I don't want to have in a particular case.

I searched on google found this .no-gutter snippet but it just remove all padding which I don't want.

```
.no-gutter > [class*='col-'] {
    padding-right:0;
    padding-left:0;
}
```

I added padding-left:0 to second column to solve the problem but it remove the padding for mobile view too (when all column takes the whole width). I know I can also solve by writing media queries for each breakpoint. But I wants to know if there is any bootstrap snippet already which can do this and also wants to if someone else has also tried to achieve this , would like to know what they have tried.

I have created an test case on JSFiddle - http://jsbin.com/wucaho/1/edit?html,css,output

And this screenshot will make you my question understand easily

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old post, but this helped me and hopefully can help somebody else in the future.

```
.no-gutter-left > [class*='col-'] {
    padding-left:0;
    padding-right:6px;
}

.no-gutter-right > [class*='col-'] {
    padding-right:0;
    padding-left:6px;
}
```

Apply .no-gutter-left to the first field (left), and apple .no-gutter-right to the second field (right).

```
<div class="form-group no-gutter-left">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <label class="sr-only">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" name="fname">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group no-gutter-right ">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <label class="sr-only">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" name="lname">
    </div>
</div>
```

If you wanted 3 columns within a row you would likely have to add a ".no-gutter-both" class with 3px padding on either side.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you mean. You can wrap the row in a custom container. I'm just going to call it "wrap".

```
.wrap {
    padding: 0 15px;
}
```

So the markup would be :

```
<div class="wrap aka-my-custom-container">
    <div class="row no-gutter">
        <div class="col-sm-4">...</div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a picture:[image]

Comment: No this is not what I want. I have replaced the picture to make the question more clear.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** You have to use media queries.. I can't find any snippet for this or other "fast 'n easy" solution. At least, the guys that make the framework use the media queries. ;)

Add this code to the bottom of your css file:

```
@media only screen and ( max-width: 479px ) {  
  .no-left-pad { padding-left: 15px; }

  .no-gutter > [class*='col-'] {
     padding-right: 15px;
     padding-left: 15px;
  }
}
```

**Edit 2** :)

You can use JS libraries to detect mobile devices and/or small screens. And on page load to add specific class to the html or body tag. For example:

```
<html class="mobile">
OR
<body class="small-screen">
```

In this way you can use this class as prefix instead of media queries.

Comment: Yes these methods I know. If I would not go with JS detection. if there is not other solution then would use media queries but will think of any better class name instead no-left-pad which should make sense on desktop and mobile both.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a class that I put on the column that I want to have no gutters:

```
[class*='col-'].gutterless {
    padding-right:0;
    padding-left:0;
}
```

So my markup looked something like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3"> left box </div>
  <div class="col-sm-9 gutterless"> right box </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for:

Example: http://jsbin.com/dovag/1